# How can I build an Angular app with many scripts and have only one script tag in my HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular, I'm building a demo app to learn, it's something very basic, but it's working, but I'd like to know how to divide this app in different files without having to write a script tag for every file.

Lets say I have my files structured like this:

Scripts/

angular.js

----App/

```
-----app.js(main app module)
```

----Factories/

```
-----factoryOne.js

-----factoryTwo.js
```

----Controllers/

```
-----controllerOne.js
-----controllerTwo.js
```

----Routes/

```
-----routes.js
```

And in my main view I just want to have

```
 <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/app/app.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to do this? like include in Java or using in C#, thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). With it, at most you will only have 2 script tags, RequireJS and your main app script. Angular will be loaded as a dependency of your app fragments that need it.

Answer (score 3):

Personally use Grunt for tasks like this. You can find details for this particular one @ https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-concat + https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-usemin. These script tags will will be in your source, but your dist version will have a single one.

This will all be set up for you if you start your project using Bower.